# How to put file path in package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I want to make a script in package.json file where I can run a file which is not present in the same directory as the package.json file but it is present in parent folder of package.json file.

I want to do it like:

```js
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon ../../ServerStarter.js",
}
```

Here I want to run the `ServerStarter.js` file but I don't know how to put the file path in there. Please Help.

Comment: If it's in the parent folder, the path should be `../`, not `../../`. If you do `../../`, it references the parent folder's parent folder.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I had just put an extra pair of ../ 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to switch to a different directory before executing your command, you could try this way.

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "cd ../../ && nodemon ServerStarter.js",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did good. But if you want the parent folder, it will be `../` instead of `../../`

Here's a short reminder :

- `./` refers to the current folder
- `../` refers to the parent folder
- `/` Is an absolute path. This is often used when an alias is used that starts at the root of the project or in the src folder. (`@/src/controller/main.ts`) for example. `@` represents the root of the project.

The difference between an absolute and a relative path is that an absolute path specifies the location from the root directory whereas a relative path is related to the current directory.

So if I want to load a file that is in the above folder, I can do this: `../myfile.js`